# Why does Python not manipulate this array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following code snippet:

```
d = [[0,558,437,142,45,290], [558,0,232,500,600,523], [437,232,0,408,492,572], 
 [142,500,408,0,180,197], [45,600,492,180,0,254], [290,523,572,197,254,0]]

for row in d:
    for elem in row:
        elem = elem * 2
print d[0][1]
print '\n'
```

Why does it not print the new value, it still prints 558

Comment: Because integers are immutable, and `elem = elem * 2` has no way to change the content of the list.

Answer (score 5):

`elem = elem * 2` modifies the value of a variable named `elem`. This variable has nothing to do with the list other than its initial value came from a list element.

To do what you want, you need indexes into the array. Alternatively, you can use the `map()` function. However, this will only create a new list with the new values rather than changing the values of the original list.

Comment: Note: the plural of `index` is `indices`.

Comment: @zondo Either is correct (source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/index)

Comment: I regret my criticism.

Comment: @zondo No worries. Such criticism is always welcome. Every once in a while someone proves me wrong ;-)

Comment: I should have attempted to back myself up with some competent authority, but as I didn't make sure, I didn't have one.  I guess next time I'll look it up _before_ offering my criticism.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning a new value to the variable `elem`.  This does not effect the list.  Instead try this:

```
d = [[0,558,437,142,45,290], [558,0,232,500,600,523], 
[437,232,0,408,492,572], 
 [142,500,408,0,180,197], [45,600,492,180,0,254], [290,523,572,197,254,0]]

for row in d:
    for index in range(len(row)):
        row[index] *= 2
print d[0][1]
print '\n'
```

Notice that I use `index` for the index to the element instead of accessing the element itself.

Comment: You might want to change the name of the variable `elem` to make it more clear that it is an index rather than an element of a list.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you.  I have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

Aside of the "why" as mentionned in other answers, here is how you can achieve this using list comprehensions:

```
d = [[0,558,437,142,45,290], [558,0,232,500,600,523], [437,232,0,408,492,572], 
 [142,500,408,0,180,197], [45,600,492,180,0,254], [290,523,572,197,254,0]]

for i, el in enumerate(d):
  d[i] = [row * 2 for row in el]

print(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this instead:

```
double_d = [[elem * 2 for elem in row] for row in d]
```

Using list comprehensions is more idiomatic Python.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this does not change the elements of the original list.

Comment: Well, instead of using a new variable `double_d` the OP can assign the result to `d` in order to destroy the original information.

Comment: Of course. Either way, this creates a new list rather than changing the elements of the existing list. I'm sure you know this. I'm pointing it out for the benefit of the OP and future readers.